# Issue with getBinaryStream(index)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am getting `null` value when I am reading the blob data from database. What might be the issue? Can some one help me on this?

```
 Connection con = null;
 PreparedStatement psStmt = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;


try {
    try {

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }
            con = 

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@MyDatabase:1535:XE","password","password");

            System.out.println("connection established"+con);

            psStmt = con
                    .prepareStatement("Select Photo from Person where Firstname=?");

            int i = 1;

            psStmt.setLong(1, "Nani");

            rs = null;

            rs = psStmt.executeQuery();

            InputStream inputStream = null;

            while (rs.next()) {

                inputStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1);

                //Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);

                //Blob blob1 = (Blob)rs.getObject(1);

                //System.out.println("blob length   "+blob1);//rs.getString(1);

            }


            System.out.println("bytessssssss   "+inputStream);//here i am getting null value.


        } catch (SQLException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe  you didn't use `setString` function to assign any value to firstname which leads to null

for example:

```
ps.preparedStatement("Select photo from person where firstname = ?");
ps.setString(1,"kick"); <----- add this line
system.out.println("bytes "+rs.getBinaryStream(1));
```

Another suggestions

there is no need to use `rs = null;` inside try catch block because you have `rs=null;` at beginning of
your code.

change

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
```

to

```
InputStream inputStream = new InputStream();
```

or

get rid of `InputStream inputStream = null;`

[source you should take a look at](http://www.herongyang.com/JDBC/SQL-Server-BLOB-getBinaryStream.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question please go through. I have done what ever you mentioned even though i am getting the same problem.

Comment: @Nani can you change InputStream inputStream = null; to InputStream inputStream = new InputStream() plz?

Comment: @Nani get rid of rs = null; inside your try catch block too

Comment: Did you indeed now use setString?

Comment: @JoopEggen the op did not use it at first place, and it added later :)

Comment: @Nani did you do the changes I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious error is using setLong instead of setString.

However one practice is fatal: declaring in advance. This in other languages is a good practice, but in java one should declare as close as possible.

**This reduces scope, by which you would have found the error!** Namely inputStream is called after a failed `rs.next()` - outside the loop. Maybe because no records were found.

This practice, declaring as near as feasible, also helps with try-with-resources which were used here to automatically close the statement and result set.

```
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:oracle:thin:@MyDatabase:1535:XE","password","password");
    System.out.println("connection established"+con);
    try (PreparedStatement psStmt = con.prepareStatement(
            "Select Photo from Person where Firstname=?")) {
        int i = 1;
        psStmt.setString(1, "Nani");
        try (ResultSet rs = psStmt.executeQuery()) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                try (InputStream inputStream = rs.getBinaryStream(1)) {
                    //Blob blob = rs.getBlob(1);
                    //Blob blob1 = (Blob)rs.getObject(1);
                    //System.out.println("blob length   "+blob1);//rs.getString(1);
                    Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get("C:/photo-" + i + ".jpg"));
                }
                ++i;
            }
            //ERROR System.out.println("bytessssssss   "+inputStream);
        } // Closes rs.
    } // Closes  psStmt.
}
```

Comment: @KickButtowski Absolute to the point, but then I also saw that the inputStream was kept _after_ the rs.next loop; hence my answer. Also because I wanted to correct the declaration style, which might become ingrown.

Answer (score 0):

1- In your code when setting the parameter's value of SQL query, be sure to use the appropriate data type of the field. So here you should use

```
psStmt.setString(1, "Nani");
```

instead of

```
psStmt.setLong(1, "Nani");
```

2- Make sure that the query is correct (Table name, field name).

3- Make sure that the table is containing data.